# Docker search and description column

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have a problem with DESCRIPTION column in Docker Toolbox.
When I am searching for example like below:
[image]

I don't see full value in DESCRIPTION column. I didn't see anything about this problem in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/#extended-description.
There is some magic trick to resolved it?

Only way is put full description into "Readme"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--no-trunc` switch:

```
# docker search --no-trunc oracle
NAME                                DESCRIPTION                                                                                          STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
oraclelinux                         Official Docker builds of Oracle Linux.                                                              536       [OK]
sath89/oracle-12c                   Oracle Standard Edition 12c Release 1 with data mount support and etc                                435                  [OK]
frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8          The smallest Docker image with OracleJDK 8 (167MB)                                                   355                  [OK]
alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g      This is a working (hopefully) Oracle XE 11.2 on top of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS                              277                  [OK]
sath89/oracle-xe-11g                Oracle xe 11g with database files mount support and graceful shutdown database files mount support   230                  [OK]
...
```

I think docker toolbox is some Windows related thing. Have tested it on Linux only but It should work on Win too, when it's a full compatible port of the Linux Docker.